# Cumulative count over dates, discarding some values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have an Answers table with the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE Answers
  ([id] int, [analyst_id] int, [date] date);
```

I have to "accumulate-count" how many answers an analyst has per month, discarding any answers given before a period of 3 months after the last answer. Given the following:

```
INSERT INTO Answers
  ([id], [analyst_id], [date])
VALUES
  (1, 1, '2017/01/01'),
  (2, 1, '2017/02/01'), -- should be discarded
  (3, 1, '2017/03/01'), -- should be discarded
  (4, 1, '2017/05/01'),
  (5, 1, '2017/06/01'), -- should be discarded
  (6, 1, '2017/07/01'), -- should be discarded
  (7, 1, '2017/08/01'),
  (8, 2, '2017/01/01'),
  (9, 2, '2017/04/01'),
  (10, 1, '2018/02/01'),
  (11, 2, '2018/03/01');
```

The expected result is:

```
analyst_id | month-year | count
-------------------------------
1          | 01/2017    | 1
1          | 02/2017    | 1
1          | 03/2017    | 1
1          | 04/2017    | 1
1          | 05/2017    | 2
1          | 06/2017    | 2
1          | 07/2017    | 2
1          | 08/2017    | 3
1          | 09/2017    | 3
1          | 10/2017    | 3
1          | 11/2017    | 3
1          | 12/2017    | 3
2          | 01/2017    | 1
2          | 02/2017    | 1
2          | 03/2017    | 1
2          | 04/2017    | 2
2          | 05/2017    | 2
2          | 06/2017    | 2
2          | 07/2017    | 2
2          | 08/2017    | 2
2          | 09/2017    | 2
2          | 10/2017    | 2
2          | 11/2017    | 2
2          | 12/2017    | 2
1          | 01/2018    | 0
1          | 02/2018    | 1
1          | 03/2018    | 1
2          | 01/2018    | 0
2          | 02/2018    | 0
2          | 03/2018    | 1
```

DBMS is a SQL Server 2012.

**EDIT**

I wrote this fiddle with my current half-solution: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c2e82e/5

Each year, the count need to be reset.

Comment: The last answer is in 2017-08.  I don't understand why it is being discarded according to your rules.

Comment: My bad. Bad explanation. 
Before that answer (august), the last accepted one was in july. The next acceptable answer will be in october.

Comment: what problem are you facing in your query?

Comment: I don't know how to achieve this. I already tried subqueries and now I would like to try some Analytical Functions like LAG, but don't know where to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**:

OK, for the updated question, you essentially need to make a "dates" table (here a CTE called "D") that contains all the dates between the minimum and maximum date in your Answers table. Then you can essentially left join your results to that and use a `DENSE_RANK()` window function to determine the count.

```
DECLARE @Answers TABLE (ID INT, Analyst_ID INT, [Date] DATE);
INSERT @Answers (ID, Analyst_ID, [Date])
VALUES
  (1, 1, '2017/01/01'),
  (2, 1, '2017/02/01'),
  (3, 1, '2017/03/01'),
  (4, 1, '2017/05/01'),
  (5, 1, '2017/06/01'),
  (6, 1, '2017/07/01'),
  (7, 1, '2017/08/01'),
  (8, 2, '2017/01/01'),
  (9, 2, '2017/04/01'),
  (10, 1, '2018/02/01'),
  (11, 2, '2018/03/01');

WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT A.Analyst_ID, [Date] = MIN(A.[Date])
    FROM @Answers AS A
    GROUP BY A.Analyst_ID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT A.Analyst_ID, A.[Date]
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT A.Analyst_ID, A.[Date], RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A.Analyst_ID ORDER BY A.ID)
        FROM @Answers AS A
        JOIN CTE 
            ON CTE.Analyst_ID = A.Analyst_ID
            AND DATEADD(MONTH, 3, CTE.[Date]) <= A.[Date]
    ) AS A
    WHERE A.RN = 1
),

D AS -- List of dates between minimum and maximum date in table for each analyst ID.
(
    SELECT [Date] = DATEADD(MONTH, RN, (SELECT MIN([Date]) FROM @Answers)),
           A.Analyst_ID
    FROM (SELECT RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1 FROM sys.objects) AS O
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Analyst_ID FROM @Answers) AS A
    WHERE RN <= (SELECT DATEDIFF(MONTH, MIN([Date]), MAX([Date])) FROM @Answers)
)

SELECT D.Analyst_ID,
       [Month-Year] = FORMAT(D.[Date], 'MM/yyyy'),
       [Count] = CASE WHEN A.[Date] IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY D.Analyst_ID, DATEPART(YEAR, A.[Date]) ORDER BY A.[Date]) END
FROM D
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM CTE WHERE CTE.[Date] <= D.[Date] AND DATEDIFF(YEAR, CTE.[Date], D.[Date]) = 0 AND CTE.Analyst_ID = D.Analyst_ID ORDER BY CTE.[Date] DESC) AS A
ORDER BY D.Analyst_ID, D.[Date];
```

Comment: I am sorry... again, my bad. I thought this was the right answer, but it is ok to skip months, and in this case, the next month (any date after 3 months) will just increment 1. So, if I only have january and october with answers, january will be 1, every month after that will also have 1, and then october will have 2.

Comment: @JonathasCosta I've edited in an updated answer based on what I think you're trying to achieve. Essentially, whatever you do, you're gonna need to fill in the gaps with the dates, which means creating some sort of dates table (for each analyst ID). After that, the process is _mostly_ the same as it was before. Here I use DENSE_RANK() and partition by year to do the count.